No Internet Connection on Mac when using Charles Proxy
I've installed Charles Proxy, but am not able to see any items in the Structure tab.
Whenever I enable MacOS Proxy and go to a webpage on Safari I get: Safari Can't Open the Page. Safari can't open the page because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection. This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes, and then try again.
On Chrome I get: This site can't be reached.The website at ___ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. ERR_TUNNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
I have gone to Help -> Install Charles Root Certificate, and then go and Trust the certificate. Allow list is unchecked.
Any ideas for why internet access is blocked while using Charles? Thanks in advance for your help.

Fixed my own problem. I had a Jupyter notebook opened to port 8888 and as soon I closed this, Charles began working as expected.
